# Django Template Broke When Model Field Type Changed From CharField to ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I had a set of templates that all start with the same object_list.  The first (reviews_list) displays every item in the object list.  The rest of them display a subset of the items based on an attribute: `{% if review.library == "Movies" %}`.

This worked fine until I changed the Review model.  Where `library` used to be a CharField, it's now a ForeignKey, though the name of the field did not change.  reviews_list still renders properly but all of the other templates are showing empty.  I have tried both of the following and everything's still empty.

On `library`'s pk as a string:
`{% if review.library == "1" %}`

On `library`'s pk as an int: `{% if review.library == 1 %}`

I had wiped the database before doing the migration, then repopulated, so there shouldn't be any weird data issues.

The template is pretty short, so pasting it below.  How can I get items to display in the template based on the value of a field that's an fk?  Thanks

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}TV Reviews{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="jumbotron-fluid">List Of TV Reviews</h1>
    {% for review in object_list %}
        {% if review.library == 'TV' %} <!-- This is the relevant line -->
            <div class="card">
                <a href="{% url 'review_detail' review.pk %}"><div class="card-header">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">
                        {{ review.title }}
                </span> &middot;
                    <span class="text-muted">by {{ review.author }} | {{ review.date }}</span>
                </div></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ review.review_body }}
                </div>
                {% if user == review.author %}
                <div class="card-footer text-center text muted"><a
                        href="{% url 'review_edit' review.pk %}">Edit</a>
                    | <a
                        href="{% url 'review_delete' review.pk %}">Delete</a>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <br />
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div align="center"><a href="{% url 'review_list' %}"><button type="button"
                                                 class="btn btn-info">Back to
    Main List</button></a></div>
{% endblock content %}
```

If it's relevant, below are the models:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    library = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lib_desc = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.library

class Review(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=DO_NOTHING,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    review_body = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=DO_NOTHING,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('review_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you changed the models, you have to update the template the same way (add another library attribute).

This should work now:

```py
{% if review.library.library == 'TV' %}
```

Note, that even though you implemented a `__str__` function, this is not called in the template for this comparision (but a print function would show the desired output).

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!